# Update priority of other records based on new /old value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with a column called `Priority` (`int`) with values from 1 to n.

E.g. I have the following 6 records with `Priority` column:

```
Col1 | Priority
-----+----------
val1 | 1
val2 | 2
val3 | 3
val4 | 4
val5 | 5
val6 | 6
```

Now if I want to change priority of the 6th record of 2, then after 2 all records priority should increment by 1. So output would be

```
Col1 | Priority
-----+---------
val1 | 1
val6 | 2
val2 | 3
val3 | 4
val4 | 5
val5 | 6
```

How can I do this in T-SQL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `case` expression:

```
update tablename
set Priority = case when Priority = 6 then 2
                    when Priority > 1 then Priority + 1
                    else Priority
               end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE` expression or `IIF()` if you are on SQL Server 2012+:

```
CREATE TABLE P (
    Col1 VARCHAR(25),
    Priority INT
    );
INSERT INTO P VALUES
('val1', 1),
('val2', 2),
('val3', 3),
('val4', 4),
('val5', 5),
('val6', 6);

UPDATE P
SET Priority = IIF(Priority = 6, 2, IIF(Priority = 1, 1, Priority + 1) );

SELECT *
FROM P
ORDER BY Priority;
```

Output:

```
| Col1 | Priority |
|------|----------|
| val1 |        1 |
| val6 |        2 |
| val2 |        3 |
| val3 |        4 |
| val4 |        5 |
| val5 |        6 |
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would like an answer for the general case (not specifically 6 and 2)
If for example you will replace 5 and 2, then you shouldn't increment the priority 6 ...

```
DECLARE @PrioriyToChange int = 6;
DECLARE @NewPrioriy int = 2;
update PriorityTable set prioirity = 
                case when prioirity = @PrioriyToChange then @NewPrioriy
                     when prioirity between @NewPrioriy and @PrioriyToChange - 1 
                          then prioirity + 1
                     else prioirity
                end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually recommend making `Priority` a `float` so that, outside of exceptional circumstances, you can always compute a new Priority value that is between any existing pair of adjacent values.

E.g. if you made `val6`s priority `1.5` then you wouldn't have to change any other row's values.

Occasionally (based on update frequencies) you can re-base the whole table using a `ROW_NUMBER()` to get values back to `int`s.

---

E.g. the rebase query (when the priority values have become too "fiddly") would be something like this:

```
declare @t table (Val char(4), Priority float)
insert into @t (Val,Priority) VALUES
('val1',1),
('val6',1.5),
('val2',2)

;With ForUpdate as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Priority) as NewPri
    from @t
)
UPDATE ForUpdate SET Priority = NewPri
select * from @t
```